# How to deal with epsilon transitions while converting NFA to DFA?

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, nfa

The start state(S0) of my NFA has 2 outgoing epsilon transitions to S1 and S2, and, S1 and S2 have further transitions, and are disjoint of each other. So do I consider {S1,S2} as one state while converting it to DFA?

Comment: This question would probably be more suitable for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The start state(S0) of my NFA has 2 outgoing epsilon transitions to S1 and S2. S1 and S2 have further transitions, and are disjoint of each other.

We consider {S1,S2} as one state while converting €-NFA to DFA. This is because the transition has € closure and they move from the same state.

For example, we have 7 states:

```
 Q={q0,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6}
 Δ={0,1}
```

We have epsilon transitions for:

```
{q0,q3,q6,q1}
```

We have two outgoing epsilon transitions

```
q5,q2 from q1, i.e., ε-closure(q1)={q2,q5}
```

From the above example we have to convert  ε-nfa to dfa.

[Epsilon NFA to DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qoq8s.jpg)

[Continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiALd.jpg)

[Final DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K27DW.jpg)